# Auto-update a column based on another column

Tags: google-sheets

Given that I have the following data in `sheet1`:

```
| id                                   | red |
|--------------------------------------|-----|
| e6282843-efc0-44f6-8989-028153adc317 | yes |
| 014c7590-5c3f-4260-b251-5098dd825688 |     |
| 6a037de4-0dc6-4e67-966b-7d6187b9d93b | yes |
```

I know that by entering `=sheet1!A2` in `sheet2` column I can grab the data and then dragging the formula will expand it as far as I want. But is there a better to sync two columns without specifying the range?

Basically, I want a column to be cloned and updated in another sheet without expanding the formula. Every time something is added to first column it should reflect on the second column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `ARRAYFORMULA`. Enter this in your Sheet 2 cell, where you want the values copied to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA('Sheet 1'!A2:B)
```

When you enter new values in Sheet 1, the new values will automatically be present in Sheet 2. Only the `A2:B` range is included.

Feel free to copy [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zKRMy9HSGfdBqXbBvIoBou1qlxo91pKOViWB6JQ9lRo/edit?usp=sharing) that I set up to test, and check the [documentation for ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275).

Comment: Awesome. Saw the `arrayformula` earlier but couldn't figure out how to use it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, `arrayformula` is in no way obvious. Glad you could use it!